# Php artisan make:auth command is not defined in Laravel 8 on ubuntu system

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run this command in laravel 8.* but it's not working.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I got error like

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined
  Did you mean one of these?  


      make:test
      make:request
      make:migration
      make:seeder
      make:middleware
      make:controller
      make:provider
      make:policy
      make:event
      make:console
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:model
      make:command
```

also I tried to solve with

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

I got this error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Comment: Install the Laravel UI package. `composer require laravel/ui`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solve this issue

changes with app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
.
.
.
.
.
.
public function boot()
{
   Schema::defaultstringLength(191);
}
```

then using command as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

then

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui:auth

php artisan optimize

php artisan serve
```

and It resolve my issue
my screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1):

first run this command `composer require laravel/ui`   then run this command

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

please follow these laravel 8 guide lines you will get your solution

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

also this is tutorial how to use auth in laravel 8

https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-8-authentication-tutorial

laravel jetstream for auth

https://dev.to/kingsconsult/laravel-8-auth-registration-and-login-32jl

Answer (score 0):

```
    laravel 8 you can write this command.its work for me.
    
    php artisan ui:auth

=>php artisan make:auth  ( which works for Laravel 5.8 and older versions )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below composer command:

```
composer update
```

Or

```
composer install
```

And after that run the `ui` command

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Then run:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, make:auth has been removed since Laravel 6 and was extracted to Laravel ui.
Regarding the error when installing these two:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

You must have a version conflict. Try to re-install it with: `composer require laravel/ui "^3.0"`